# How to import a mysql backup to mongodb?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, migration

Import in mongodb from mysql, it's possible?

Comment: Nopes. MySQL is a relational database. MongoDB is a NoSQL document database. Completely different. You'd have to write a script to migrate the MySQL database structure into a MongoDB data structure.

Comment: use Tungsten replicator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on what Flukey said; you need to write a script which will do this for you; there isn't a direct export -> import as MySQL is a relational database, where as MongoDB is a NoSQL database.

For further understanding on NoSQL you can read here: [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)

You can do something like export to CSV and import into mongo as described in this article [CSV Import](http://blog.sarathonline.com/2010/12/import-mysql-data-or-csv-file-into.html) however, it's very likely that your schema is going to be different in NoSQL compared to MySQL; so it's really worth designing your schema to fit the data then migrate over.

Comment: Yikes; my answer is extremely out-dated. Since answering there have been a significant number of scripts to do exactly this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.You can use my plugin. But for that you have to write data transformation configuration.

http://code.google.com/p/sql-to-nosql-importer/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Automated export/import using r2n mappings:
https://github.com/virtimus/mysql2mongo

Answer (score 2):

You can use mongify http://mongify.com/
This will reduce the labour all u need to give is database credentials

And its opensource too

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use this class,
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8757-PHP-Import-MySQL-database-into-MongoDB.html#information

Comment: Please avoid link only answers in the future. Stale links help no one.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple, but imperfect (due to structural differences), way to do this is to use [MongoVue](http://www.mongovue.com/2010/07/30/import-data-from-mysql/).  The import tool costs $35 (not included in the free version).  I have only used this to import data from SQL Server to MongoDB, but I have got good results very quickly this way.